# Как в JSTL делать проверку на последний элемент в карте Map?

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

Доброго времени суток.
Есть такая задача: в JSP, при помощи `JSTL` (`<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>`) реализовать вывод информации в JSON-формате. И никак иначе. Задача простая, не требующая особых усилий. Но вот затормозил я именно на простой задачке. Надо реализовать вывод в массиве карты `Map<String, String>`. Я сделал это так:

```
[
<c:forEach var="item" items="${payParam.format}">
    "<c:out value="${payParam.description}"/>":"<c:out value="${item.value}" />",
</c:forEach>
]
```

Проблема в том, что в конце строки, после каждого цикла, всегда запятая. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как мне делать проверку на то, нужна ли запятая? Т.е. если элемент в карте последний, то запятая не нужна.

Comment: запятая - это следствие метода toString(), обычно убирается методом replace(), в конце ее не должно быть. Откуда мы знаем нужна ли тебе запятая?) Проверку делать - если элемент последний, то.. =)

Comment: Проверку делать - если элемент последний, то.. =) .... то запятая не нужна, как гласит последнее предложение. При использовании моего кода, запятая всегда ставится в конце строки при каждой итерации. Мне же надо, чтобы ее не было, если элемент последний. Тут главная суть вопроса - проверка на то, последний ли элемент в карте. Также мне не ясно, как же вы сможете убрать последнюю запятую методом toString()? Надо ведь допустить возможность того, что после этого массива и дальше могуд быть какие-либо JSON-элементы. Т.е. запятые будут и дальше встречаться.

Comment: ну тогда, если у тебя длина строки статическая, т.е. фиксированное кол-во элементов в ней, тогда можно просто написать условие, типа после 5ого элемента - запятую не ставить

Comment: Не подходит. Неизвестно сколько элементов в карте. Может, это как-то можно вычислить? Идея достойна жизни!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все это делается легко при помощи свойства [isLast](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/jsp/jstl/core/LoopTagStatus.html#isLast%28%29) класса `LoopTagStatus`. Для этого, в объявлении итерации задаем еще один параметр: `varStatus="loop"`. Далее, можно посмотреть, последний ли это элемент при помощи объявления:

```
<c:if test="${!loop.last}">,</c:if>
```

В итоге получится вот что:

```
[
<c:forEach var="item" items="${payParam.format}" varStatus="loop">
    "<c:out value="${payParam.description}"/>":"<c:out value="${item.value}" />"
    <c:if test="${!loop.last}">,</c:if>
</c:forEach>
]
```

Comment: сам задал вопрос, сам ответил - идеальный пользователь

Comment: @Viacheslav, тут ничего удивительного! У меня проект, который надо делать. Я задал вопрос в надежде на то, что в скором времени на него ответят. Но в это время я тоже времени не терял, ожидая манны небесной, и искал ответ на свой вопрос. Ну и, не получив ответа, я отыскал его сам.