# Первый элемент в Map на JSP

Tags: java, jsp, map, jstl

Как получить первый элемент на *jsp* странице из `Map`.

```
Map<Long,MyObject> map = ......
model.addAttribute("statuses", map);
```

Имеется такой код на *JPS* странице.

```
<c:set var="myvalue" value="${statuses[0].value.myfield}"/> //error
<c:forEach var="status" items="${statuses}">
 ....
</c:forEach>
```

Как правильно получить первый элемент который будет в цикле `forEach`?

Comment: Не совсем понятно. Вы хотите выполнить итерацию по вашей хеш-таблице?

Answer (score 1):

Правильнее всего вот так

```
model.addAttribute("firstStatus", CollectionUtils.first(map.values()));
```

`CollectionUtils.first()` можно реализовать или в библиотеках поискать.

Да, и надо учитывать, что понятие первого элемента сильно зависит от реализации `Map`.

Comment: Не очень хорошая идея добавлять дополнительные данные на модель. Было бы идеально решить без этого.

Comment: @Vurtatoo Предпочитаю правило — JSP для разметки и только. Дополнительные конструкции только на крайний случай.

Answer (score 1):

Можно попробовать так:

```
<c:forEach var="status" items="${statuses}" begin="0" end="0">
....
</c:forEach>
```

Т. е. по вашей коллекции будет выполнена всего одна итерация по первому элементу.

Если обработке подлежат и остальные элементы коллекции, то первый элемент можно проверять через `c:if` и `c:forEach ... varStatus="status"`. Похожий вопрос со статусной переменной [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/130048/)

PS Код не проверял, но идея должна быть понятна.

Answer (score 1):

Если реализация Map не важна, то вы можете вместо интерфейса взять его конкретную реализацию. Например `TreeMap`, который реализует метод `firstEntry`.

На jsp странице для вызова метода потребуется приведение типов.